the trait `diesel::Expression` is not implemented for `IpNetwork`, which is required by `&'insert IpNetwork: AsExpression<diesel::sql_types::Inet>`
I add a postgresql table net_test like this:
CREATE TABLE public.net_test (
    net inet NOT NULL,
    id int8 NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT net_pk PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

then add diesel model file like this which followed https://docs.diesel.rs/2.1.x/diesel/pg/sql_types/struct.Inet.html:
use std::fmt::Display;

use serde::Serialize;
use serde::Deserialize;
use crate::model::diesel::dolphin::dolphin_schema::*;
use bigdecimal::BigDecimal;
use chrono::DateTime;
use chrono::offset::Utc;
use ipnetwork::IpNetwork;
    #[derive(Insertable,Queryable,QueryableByName,Debug,Serialize,Deserialize,Default,Clone)]
    #[diesel(table_name = net_test)]
    pub struct NetTest {
        pub net: IpNetwork,
        pub id: i64,
    }

this is the schema file:
table! {
    net_test (id) {
        net -> Inet,
        id -> Int8,
    }
}

when I compile the project, shows error like this:
the trait `diesel::Expression` is not implemented for `IpNetwork`, which is required by `&'insert IpNetwork: AsExpression<diesel::sql_types::Inet>`

what should I do to fixed this issue? this is the diesel dependency config:
diesel = { version = "2.2.1", features = [
    "postgres",
    "64-column-tables",
    "chrono",
    "serde_json",
    "numeric",
    "ipnet-address"
] }


What's IpNetwork, why do you think it can be inserted into a table? Please add a [mre]!

IpNetwork was the inet mapping in diesel, I am using the ipnetwork = "0.20" as the dependencies

The documentation you linked to says "This type can only be used with feature = "network-address" or feature = "ipnet-address"." Have you done that? Did you pick "network-address"? If you have and it still doesn't work, please provide your dependencies.

I have enabled this feature in the Cargo.toml.

Enable the "network-address" feature instead. The "ipnet-address" feature is for enabling support for ipnet types, but you aren't using that crate; you're using the ipnetwork crate.
